# Optimizing my site - eTags

Tags: last-modified

ySlow is saying I have 30 misconfigured etages on http://www.diablo-source.com/ and I'm not sure what that means or how to fix it.  After a quick Google search it appears to be the same thing as a last-modified header.  Is it possible for me to setup my server so it sends the `last-modified` and `etag` header as the default last modified timestamp of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the same thing as the last-modified-header, it's a "better", safer way to identify the version of a file and was introduced with HTTP 1.1. One technical fact is that the ETags are different on different Servers, so you may can get a problem if you 'r using a CDN. I would advise you to disable E-Tags, in Apache you just need to add: `FileETag none` . http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#fileetag